# A necessary and sufficient condition for subspaces in R

Tags: linear-algebra

Good evening. Can you help me with this please? 
Are given scalars $a_1,a_2,...,a_n,c\in\mathbb{R}$  prove that the set $X=\{(x_1,...,x_n):a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n=c\}$ is a subspace of  $\mathbb{R^n}$ if and only if $c=0$.

I have already shown the first implication but do not know how I can deal the second implication?

For the first implication by the axioms of vector space reaches c = 0 and even found that the dimension of this subspace would be $n-1$

Comment: $X$ is a subspace $\Rightarrow (0,0,0,\dots,0)\in X\Rightarrow c=0$.  On the other hand, If $c=0\Rightarrow$ if $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in X$ and $(y_1,\dots,y_n)\in X$ it follows that $(x_1-y_1,\dots,x_n-y_n)\in X$ so $X$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$.  There are a few missing details, but that is the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way: Define $Lx = \sum_k a_k x_k$, then if $c=0$, we see that
$X = \ker L$, and the kernel of a linear operator is a subspace.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @HendrikMatamoros: You are very welcome!